# SharePoint 2019: MySite person.aspx stuck on "we're almost ready"

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, sharepoint-on-prem, my-site, onedrive

We are currently encountering a strange behaviour when we reach the URL */person.aspx* where we are stuck with the message "*we're almost ready*".

The problem occurs in our different *SharePoint 2019* environments with our *WebApplication* dedicated to *OneDrive*.

Our settings are the following ones:

*WebApplication* dedicated to *OneDrive*

- **Authentication:** NTLM + ADFS
- **Special policy applied to everyon for MySite:** create subsites; view pages; browser user information; open
- **Self-Service site creation:** On; Hide the create command
- **Managed paths:** personal; wilcard inclusion
- **User Profile Service Application:** all accounts are synchronized; site naming format set to resolve conflicts by using domain_username; My Site newsfeed enabled

Regarding the permissions for the *User Profile Service Application*, we did the following things:

- **NT AUTORITY\Authenticated Users:** create personal site, follow people and edit profile, use tags and notes
- **All Authenticated Users:** create personal site, follow people and edit profile, use tags and notes
- **All Users (trusted: adfs provider for sharepoint):** create personal site, follow people and edit profile, use tags and notes

The *Distributed Cache* is also started and running.

We also have another *WeAbbplication* dedicated to *SharePoint Team Sites* with its own instance of the *User Profile Service* where the *My Site Host* location is set to target the one set for the *OneDrive WebApplication*.

We have various environments with the following configuration:

- **DEV:** 1 Front End Server, 1 SQL Server
- **TEST:** 1 Front End Server, 1 SQL Server
- **STAGING:** 1 Front End Server, 1 Application Server, 1 SQL Server
- **PRODUCTION:** 2 Front End Servers, 1 Application Server, 2 SQL Servers

Our *WebApplications* have the same settings in every environment. However, we got the same problem everywhere. The more relevant error we spotted in the logs in the following one:

```
Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialFeedManager.GetFeedFor: Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialException:  No personal site exists for the current user, and no further information is available. Internal type name: Microsoft.Office.Server.Microfeed.MicrofeedException. Internal error code: 78.    
at Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialUtil.TryTranslateExceptionAndThrow(Exception exception)    
at Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialUtil.InvokeWithExceptionTranslation[T](ISocialOperationManager target, String name, Func`1 func)    
at Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialFeedManager.<>c__DisplayClass4e`1.<S2SInvoke>b__4d()    
at Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialUtil.InvokeWithExceptionTranslation[T](ISocialOperationManager target, String name, Func`1 func)    
at Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialFeedManager.<>c__DisplayClass31.<GetFeedFor>b__2f()    
at Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialUtil.InvokeWithExceptionTranslation[T](ISocialOperationManager target, String name, Func`1 func)
```

After hours of research on the Internet, we checked all the following settings:

- Policies on *WebApplication* dedicated to *OneDrive*
- *Managed path* "personal" on *WebApplication* dedicated to *OneDrive*
- Permissions for the *User Profile Service Application*
- Status of the *Distributed Cache*
- Restart *Timer Service*
- Run "*User Profile Service Application - Activity Feed Job*" manually

We tried to delete the generated *Site Collections* in the *WebApplication* dedicated to *OneDrive* for various users, but no change happened. We also tried to set a higher value manually for "*Personal Site Capabilities*", but with no more success. What it is interesting is that the field "*Personal site*" is correctly filed.

Users are authenticated through ADFS. In the *User Profile Service Application*, the account name is the *UPN*, looking like "*i:0e.t|adfs provider for sharepoint|userlogon@domain.com*". When our various users try to reach our *WebApplications*, they are firstly redirect to *adfs.domain.com*. So, in our *OneDrive WebApplication*, URL will look like */personal/username(_domain_com)*. That value matches with the "*Personal site*" field.

Currently, we are running *SharePoint Server 2019 16.0.10337.12109* with *16.0.10359.20000 Security Patch*. Our configuration database version is *16.0.10359.20000*. Language dependent patches are also installed.

The *OneDrive WebApplication* seems to work well. The problem only occurs when a user tries to reach */person.aspx*.

Has anyone encountered such a behaviour? Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance!

Best regards,

Comment: What auth method are the users using? Is that identity identical to their identity in the UPSA? To verify, you're applying both the security patch *and* language dependent fix for the given month?

Comment: Many thanks for your quick answer! I updated the question with more information. I hope it makes things a little bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for my farm:

- i've updated "Web Server
  Extensions\16\TEMPLATE\SiteTemplates\SPSPERS\XML\onet.xml" by adding
  the feature "b2741073-a92b-4836-b1d8-d5e9d73679bb" at Configuration
  ID 10;
- i've deleted the template of mysites and i've created it again;
- The issue is solved for every new mysite created.

I found the solution at this link:
https://thesharepointfarm.com/2016/03/unable-to-provision-social-features-in-sharepoint-server-2016/